# How to change the default Visual Studio project location

Tags: visual-studio-2013

Is it possible to set the default project of Visual Studio, similar to Eclipse Workspace ?

I know I can shift projects to different drives later on, but How to create a project in specific location and how would I do that?

Comment: As this? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181383.aspx

Comment: did you checked the documentation about workspaces and if you did, what can't you do? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181383.aspx

Comment: i am not talking about team workspaces, i was talking about local workspace. If I am not using Team Projects my projects are created and stored in Documents. I want them to be created in my desired location.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Tools --> Options --> Projects and Solutions --> Project Location.

Comment: Note that Visual Studio doesn't refer to this location as the "workspace" like Eclipse does. Workspace refers to some sort of clone of a team project.

Comment: Simple, useful. Thanks

Comment: In Visual Studio 2022 it is now Tools --> Options --> Projects and Solutions--> Locations --> Project Location

To future proof just search Options for 'Project location'

Comment: Currently, the final branch of the tree is called "Locations" instead of "Project Location".

Answer (score 4):

To set default path for cloning Git Repository:
Tools-->Options-->Source Control-->Git Global Settings-->Default Location

Answer (score 0):

Slight name change in the latest location on vs2022;

Tools > Options... > Projects and Solutions > Locations > Project location:

[image]
[image]

The path for the default git remains.

Tools > Options... > Source control > Git Global Settings > Default location:

[image]